# Approximating $f^{-1}(-1)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inverse-function

I'm supposed to approximate $f^{-1}(-1)$ correct to $1$ decimal place from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vg5L.jpg) graph of $f$. From the graph it's obvious that $f(-1)=-1$ which would imply $f^{-1}(-1)=-1$. However, the question asks me to "approximate" $f^{-1}(-1)$ which implies that I'm doing something wrong but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. They could be using "approximate" carelessly, or (more likely) they are including that word because any such visual estimation from observing a graph is inherently approximate. For example, can you really distinguish this graph from a similar one in which $f^{-1}(-1) = -1.00005$?